# Looping over vectors in python (analogous to Pandas columns)

Tags: python, pandas, vector, iteration

I have a number of analogous operations that I would like to perform on different vectors. What is the 'pythonesque' way of 'looping' over these variables to save lines?

```
import numpy as np

length = 10

l = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
r = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
v = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
w = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
q = np.ones(length, dtype = int)

new_l = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
new_r = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
new_v = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
new_w = np.ones(length, dtype = int)
new_q = np.ones(length, dtype = int)

l = 0.05 * new_l + 0.95 * l
r = 0.05 * new_r + 0.95 * r
v = 0.05 * new_v + 0.95 * v
w = 0.05 * new_w + 0.95 * w
q = 0.05 * new_q + 0.95 * q
```

If these were columns in a Pandas dataframe, I would write:

```
import pandas as pd

length = 10

df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(length))

for v in ['l', 'r', 'v', 'w', 'q']:
    
    df[f'{v}'] = 1
    df[f'new_{v}'] = 1
    df[f'{v}'] =  0.05 * df[f'new_{v}'] + 0.95 * df[f'{v}']
```

What's the most elegant way to do this for vectors?

Comment: Just make a matrix (an 'array' in numpy terminology) with these vectors as columns, and do the operation once in the whole matrix.

Comment: But then I need five more lines in the end to separate the output matrix into separate vectors, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack them into a single array with `np.stack()` and then apply the operations on the resulting array:

```
array = np.stack([l, r, v, w, q])
new_array = np.stack([new_l, new_r, new_v, new_w, new_q])

result = 0.05*new_array + 0.95*array
l, r, v, w, q = result
l
```

Output:

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Thanks! But then I need five more lines in the end to separate the output matrix into separate vectors, right? Is there a quick way doing this, giving it the old names (l, r, v, w, q)?

Comment: @eigenvector ```l, r, v, w, q = result```

Comment: @eigenvector I've changed it to give the output vectors the same names as the input